# Updating firebase user picture not rendering new photo until reloading app

Tags: firebase, react-native, rendering, react-props, react-native-elements

I am updating a user profile picture and am able to see the image changing in the database.  I am storing the location of the image in profile picture.  I am able to see the change happen when reloading the app and am able to see the image in firebase storage change instantly.

Here is the structure:

[image]

Here is the function I am using to change the image:

```
export const changeUserAvatar = (userId, imageUrl) => {
    firebaseService
      .database()
      .ref('users/' + userId)
      .update({
        profilePicture: imageUrl
      });
  };
```

And here is how I am rendering the image:

```
<Avatar size="xlarge" rounded source={{ uri: this.props.profilePicture }} onPress={this.openPicker}/> :
```

I am using redux to manage the state and would think it would automatically re-render with an updating value of profile picture.  I have tried everything in here:

```
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9195

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12606
```

And when I try to add something like this I don't get an image at all and it shows up as a blank screen:

```
{{uri: profilePicture + '?' + new Date()}}
```

I am facing the same issue for when I navigate back to my messages list/ the picture only changes when I do a hard reload on the app.

Comment: How are you feeding you component with the URL? Are you getting a URL after uploading it to firebase and dispatching action? how are you updating `profilePicture ` value?

Comment: I am dispatching an action for user success but simply updating the URL from the changeUserAvatar function.  That maybe the issue/ how would I dispatch an action that sends the new profile value.  I thought since I am changing the actual value in the DB and loading the URL via a map state to props the component would see this and rerender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got solution of this issue:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.photoUrl && prevProps.photoUrl !== this.props.photoUrl) {
        this.setState({ profilePicture: this.props.photoUrl })
    }
}
```

Basically, I just decided to store the new picture as a state instead.